# ContentBlockByName not resolving within AMP mime-type

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, amp4email

We're very excited about using the new AMP mime-type available within SFMC, but are experiencing some troubles with the AMPscript Functional Reference ContentBlockbyName not resolving within the code.

For example, we created an HTML Content Block saved as "**test_block**" in the following directory: "**Content Builder\My Emails\AMP**"

```
<p>Test Code block </p>
```

Then we created a new Email Message with HTML and AMP creation type.

In the HTML and AMP code, we used the follow AMPscript fuction:

```
%%=ContentBlockByName("Content Builder\My Emails\AMP\test_block")=%%
```

The content block pulls through correctly in the HTML version of the email message, but nothing is pulling through in the AMP version of the email message. Other AMPscript functionality such as setting and rendering variables seems to be working fine in the AMP version.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [help documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_ceb_amp_best_practices.htm&type=5) ContentBlockBy AMPscript functions (ContentBlockByName, ContentBlockById or ContentBlockByKey) are not supported in AMP emails.